# Pulling up "dict" value of nested JSON by one level

Tags: python, list, dictionary, chef-infra

I'm looking at converting some Chef run_lists to tags, and would like to automate the process.

So far what I've done is created a variable that runs:

```
# write to file instead of directly to variable for archival purposes
os.system("knife search '*:*' -a expanded_run_list -F json > /tmp/hostname_runlist.json")
data = json.load(open('/tmp/hostname_runlist.json'))
```

From there, I have a dict within a dict with list values similar to this:

```
{u'abc.com': {u'expanded_run_list': None}}
{u'foo.com': {u'expanded_run_list': u'base::default'}}
{u'123.com': {u'expanded_run_list': [u'utils::default', u'base::default']}}
...
```

I would like to convert that to a more simpler dictionary by removing the 'expanded_run_list' portion, as it it's not required at this point, so in the end it looks like this:

```
abc.com:None
foo.com:'base::default'
123.com:['utils::default', 'base::default']
```

I would like to keep the values as a list, or a single value depending on what is returned. When I run a 'for statement' to iterate, I can pull the hostnames from i.keys, but would need to remove the expanded_run_list key from i.values, as well as pair the key values up appropriately.

From there, I should have an easier time to iterate through the new dictionary when running an os.system Chef command to create the new tags. It's been a few years since I've written in python, so am a bit rusty. Any descriptive help would be much appreciated.

Comment: As a reminder, PyChef exists. Probably don't scrape knife.

Comment: `import chef; chef.autoconfigure()`. All laid out in the docs.

Comment: I'd like to use the chef.autoconfigure() method, but would like to disable SSL verification due to SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED (hosting my own dev cert). I see that chef.ChefAPI allows for ssl_verify=False. Can I auto-configure ssl verification, or do I need to call chef.ChefAPI and use it for each chef query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that you are having your list of `dict` objects as:

```
my_list = [
     {u'abc.com': {u'expanded_run_list': None}},
     {u'foo.com': {u'expanded_run_list': u'base::default'}},
     {u'123.com': {u'expanded_run_list': [u'utils::default', u'base::default']}}
]
```

Then, in order to achieve your desired result, you may use a combination of *list comprehension* and *dict comprehension* as:

**For getting the list of nested dictionary**

```
[{k: v.get('expanded_run_list') for k, v in l.items()} for l in my_list]
```

which will return you the list of dict objects in your desired form as:

```
[
     {u'abc.com': None}, 
     {u'foo.com': u'base::default'}, 
     {u'123.com': [u'utils::default', u'base::default']}
 ]
```

Above solution assumes that you only want the value of *key* `'expanded_run_list'` to be picked up from each of your nested dictionary. In case it doesn't exists, `dict.get` will return `None` which will be set as *value* in your resultant dict.

**For pulling up your nested dictionary to form single dictionary**

```
{k: v.get('expanded_run_list') for l in my_list for k, v in l.items()}
```

which will return:

```
{
     'foo.com': 'base::default', 
     '123.com': ['utils::default', 'base::default'], 
     'abc.com': None
}
```

Comment: One thing I've caught was that it turns a dict into a list. I would still like it as a dict to pull keys (host) and arrays (run_list).

Comment: @hobbes, it isn't converting any `dict` to `list`. It is keeping the structure as it is, and just pulling up the value of `'expanded_run_list'` one level up. Do you want all your hosts to be present in same dictionary as keys? (currently they are in different dictionary same as in your sample input)

Comment: I've read up on comprehensions, and played around for a couple of hours, and can turn it into a dict breaking it down in two lines: for l in chef_list: (line break) hr = {k: v.get('expanded_run_list') for k, v in l.items()}. hr now returns values as a dict, but when I try to apply it to a dict comprehension: hr = {k: v.get('expanded_run_list') for k, v in l.items()} for l in chef_list, I get invalid syntax on the 'for l in chef_list' statement. Any insight on what I'm missing here regarding the dict comprehension?

Comment: Just saw your post after I placed my reply. That is correct, I would like to turn it into a new dict where it only uses the host as the key, and the expanded_run_list values as the host values (but keeping list values intact).

Comment: For your first requirement to get it as single dict, your comprehension should be like:  `{k: v.get('expanded_run_list') for l in my_list for k, v in l.items()}`. Now do you want all the value to be of list type? currently I see that `'foo.com'` hold the string value for `'expanded_run_list'` key. Do you want to type-cast it to list?

Comment: That last one did it, results and type looks good and exactly what I'm after. You've helped me understand quite a lot about dict comprehension tonight, I'll try to apply more comprehensions in my daily routine. Thank you!

Comment: Awesome. I am glad that I was able to help you. Have a nice weekend!